# How to append 3 latest results onto the user’s name in Python?

Tags: python, append, text-files

I am using Python to generate a maths quiz and store the results from the quiz along with the user's name in a text file. I plan to store the last three scores of the user by appending onto the user's name if it already exists in the text file and deleting older scores if there are more than three. This is what I have done so far:

```
with open("class%s.txt" % classnumber, "a") as my_class:

    my_class.write("{0}\n".format([name, score]))

with open("class%s.txt" % classnumber, "r+")as file:

  file.seek(0)

    scores = file.readlines()

user_scores = {}

for line in scores:

    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')

    score = int(score)

    if name not in user_scores:

        user_scores[name] = []       

    user_scores[name].append(score)  

    if len(user_scores[name]) > 3:   

        user_scores[name].pop(0)
```

when I try to run this code, the following error message pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "H:\Documents\Documents\Computing\Programming tasks\task 2 - Copy 

(2).py", line 56, in <module>

name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong please.

Comment: you would get this error if some of the lines in your file do not contain `' - '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to unpack `line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')` into two values, putting one into `name` and the other into `score`. However, it only found one thing in there, so it doesn't have anything to assign to `score`. Somewhere in a `classn.txt` file is a line that doesn't come in the form `x - y`, so when you try to `split()` it, it only produces one value.

You also shouldn't need to `rstrip()` the `line` as far as I can tell, because it's coming from `readlines()`, which basically splits the file on `'\n'` anyway.

Comment: You can also put the `line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')` in a `try` block, with an `except` that says `print(line)` so you can see what `line` is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for all the help! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Sure thing. Feel free to upvote/accept if this helped solve the problem.